# How to give ResourceDictionary Source in WPF with folder structure

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

In a WPF application, Resources.xaml(Resource Dictionary) is placed in Resources folder and GetStarted.xaml(UserCOntrol) is placed in Views folder. Wizard.xaml(UserControl) is in the root folder.

Now, in Wizard.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResousrceDictionary Source="Resources/Resources.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

works fine.

I'm not sure how to access it In GetStarted.xaml,

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="component/Resources/Resources.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

doesn't work.

Please help me. I'm new to WPF.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try AssemblyTitle in your source like below:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/YourProjectAssemblyTitle;component/Resources/Resources.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Comment: The ``/YourProjectAssemblyTitle;component`` part is optional. ``Source="/Resources/Resources.xaml"`` will work just as well.